# Running a Docker image command in a mounted folder

Tags: clojure, leiningen, docker, ubuntu-13.04

I'm trying to execute `lein run` in [a Clojure Docker image](https://index.docker.io/u/jphackworth/docker-clojure/) out of a mounted folder that is not `/`, but when I try to `cd` into a folder, Docker complains with `unable to locate cd`:

```
docker run -v /root/chortles:/test -i jphackworth/docker-clojure cd /test && lein run
=> Unable to locate cd
```

How do I instruct Leiningen to run in a different folder, or tell Docker to change the directory prior to running my command?

Comment: It looks like your problem is that "cd" is not a program (and can't be: it would have to change the working directory of its parent process). Rather, it's a shell builtin. I don't know docker, so I don't know what the solution is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `-w` param for `docker run`. This parameter is useful for specifying working directory within container.

```
docker run -w /test -v /root/chortles:/test -i jphackworth/docker-clojure lein run
```

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to add a shell script to the docker image and call that.

Have a script called, say lein-wrapper.sh, install in in /usr/local/bin. The script should sort out the environment for leiningen and then call it. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH=${LEININGEN_INSTALL}:${PATH}
cd /test
lein $@
```

You can set

```
ENTRYPOINT["/usr/local/bin/lein-wrapper.sh"]
```

In your `Dockerfile`

And invoke it as:

```
# Will call /usr/local/bin/lein-wrapper.sh run 
# which will call lein run   
docker run -v /root/chortles:/test -i jphackworth/docker-clojure run

# or run lein deps...
docker run -v /root/chortles:/test -i jphackworth/docker-clojure deps
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd` is a [bash builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands), not a command. You can use `bash -c 'cd /test && lein run'`. Better yet, do as @Jiri states and use the `-w` parameter to set the working directory of the container, then just use `lein run` to start your app.